# "Haven't you?" or "don't you?"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, british-english, questions, question-tags

What is the right question tag (in British English) when we use the verb **have**?
I have interviewed a few native speakers and none of them could explain why sometimes they prefer "haven't/hasn't" and why other times they prefer "don't/doesn't".
Here are 4 different groups of sentences. Which ones are correct and which ones aren't and why?

**Group 1**

1. I've got a good voice, haven't I?
2. You've got a dog, haven't you?
3. She's got a new boyfriend, hasn't she?
4. We've got very good friends, haven't we?
5. They've got our address, haven't they?

**Group 2**

1. I have a good voice, don't I?
2. You have a dog, don't you?
3. She has a new boyfriend, doesn't she?
4. We have very good friends, don't we?
5. They have our address, don't they?

**Group 3**

1. I've got a good voice, don't I?
2. You've got a dog, don't you?
3. She's got a new boyfriend, doesn't she?
4. We've got very good friends, don't we?
5. They've got our address, don't they?

**Group 4**

1. I have a good voice, haven't I?
2. You have a dog, haven't you?
3. She has a new boyfriend, hasn't she?
4. We have very good friends, haven't we?
5. They have our address, haven't they?

Comment: I will not spell every detail out but please note: English has two present tenses for have: have/have got, and they mean exactly the same thing in AmE and BrE and have exactly the same helping verbs in their standard forms. "I've got a good voice, haven't ?" The auxiliary matches the verb: have (do/does) or have got (has/have).

Comment: Group 3 does not work for me (UK).  "I've got a good voice..." = I have got a good voice.  The tag question that follows needs to invert the auxiliary which is 'have' not 'do' - "haven't I".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the wikipedia article on *[question tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)*:

> The English tag question is made up of an auxiliary verb and a pronoun. The auxiliary has to agree with the tense, aspect and modality of the verb in the preceding sentence. If the verb is in the present perfect, for example, the tag question uses has or have; if the verb is in a present progressive form, the tag is formed with am, are, is; if the verb is in a tense which does not normally use an auxiliary, like the present simple, the auxiliary is taken from the emphatic do form; and if the sentence has a modal auxiliary, this is echoed in the tag.

But then later on:

> If the main verb is *to have*, either solution (*does/has*) is possible

Using this rule, group 2 and group 4 would both be correct.  (As an AmE, I prefer group 2 with group 4 sounding awkward to a degree approaching incorrect, but I'm unsure about BritE)

Following the same rule, group 1 would be correct and group 3 incorrect as  *has/have* is the auxiliary verb, and so it should be used in the question.  However, as a native AmE speaker, this actually runs counter to my intuition as I would prefer group 3.  I have a feeling this has to do with the *'have got'* construction somehow affecting things.

*Edit: updated because I should have read the whole thing*

Comment: So going by wikipedia, only groups 1 and 2 would be correct. Is that right? Is that how these are actually used in the U.K?

Comment: @PeterShor - Yeah, you caught me mid-edit there.  1 and 2 are correct by the 'rule' from WP.  As my edit states though, I prefer group 3 to group 1, but I'm AmE.  I agree with your other comment that group 1 sounds more 'British', though I'll leave it up to the UK natives to answer that definitively.

Comment: But in the Wikipedia page that you quoted it says: "If the main verb is to have, either solution is possible: - He has a book, hasn't he? / - He has a book, doesn't he?" This would seem to suggest that Group 4 is correct. What do you think?

Comment: @Martina - See my edit above from a few min ago.

Comment: 'AmE' appears in two places in the answer, and one place in the comment @Dusty. Just an observation...

Comment: I don't think, we in India can ever follow the examples in Gr. 3.

Comment: Group 3 is "non standard".

Answer (score 5):

In British English groups 1, 2 and 4 would be  accepted as grammatically correct, though group 4 examples sound outdated. Group 3 examples would be defined as incorrect.

But language is defined by the people who use it, not by grammar books. I have the feeling group 3 examples are used more and more often, as AmE use is spread even among BrE speakers. Therefore, when you hear native English speakers use the examples you cite, it's safe for you to do the same.

Comment: "Group 3 examples ... incorrect." - What grammar rule do these infringe?  Presumably something that allows "She's got a new boyfriend, hasn't she?" (1) and "She has a new boyfriend, doesn't she?" (2) but not "She's got a new boyfriend, doesn't she?" (3).

Comment: @jwpat7: The rule is that you use the same auxiliary verb in the tag as appeared in the original sentence. See Dusty's answer.  You can't say "She's moved to London, didn't she," because that follows "have" with "did". In American English, the participle "got" is an exception to the rule (not "gotten" -- that follows the rule). I'm now wondering whether British English speakers who use "do" with "have got" distinguish between the different meanings of the word "got" the way Americans do.

Comment: @Peter: You bring up a good point, but note that your "She's moved" example is fundamentally different from the examples in the question. When we say "She has a dog", "has" is a verb indicating possession. When we say "She has moved", "has" is not a stand-alone verb but a tense modifer for "moved". (I hadn't thought of that construct when I gave my answer and I would have answered somewhat differently if I had.)

Comment: @Jay: I thought that my "She's moved" example parallels the "She's got" construction of groups 1 and 3. The participles "moved" and "got" aren't treated any differently in standard British English.

Comment: @Jay: You're right that "have" (like "do" and "be") can be used both as an auxiliary and as a substantive verb. "Be" always patterns as an auxiliary even when it is substantive ("Is he?", "He's not" rather than "*Does he be?" "*He doesn't be"). "Do" never patterns as an auxiliary when it is substantive ("*He don't it"). But in British English "have" is like "be", and can pattern like an auxiliary even when it is substantive: "Have you [got] any?" Fifty years ago this was the only option: "Do you have ..." would not have been said by many Britons.

Comment: English has two, repeat two, present tense forms to indicate "possess something": have and have got. Both in AmE and BrE. And funnily enough, this is very confusing even to English speakers. And everyone goes crazy with the fact that the AmE present perfect of **get** is  **have gotten** whereas the BrE one is **have got**, which is the same as the present tense of "have got" as in have something.

Comment: I am not sure you can say that Group 3 where the auxiliaries are mismatched is only AmE. I personally don't use the do auxiliary if I use have got as a present tense. What does seem to be **very American** is: Got milk? Yeah, I got milk. for I have milk. And that "got milk" is, a shortened form of: Have you got milk?

Answer (score 1):

I think all your examples are grammatically correct and would be well understood by any English speaker. It's just a matter of choice of words. It's like the difference between asking, "Does she have a dog?", "Does she own a dog?", "Has she got a dog?", etc. All are equally valid and mean essentially the same thing.

Personally I think the "haven't I" construct is a little unusual and awkward. Expand the contractions and you're saying, "She has got a dog, has she not?" We don't use this construct with any word other than "to have" that I can think of. All others we use versions of "to do". We don't say, "She runs very fast, runs she not?", or "She eats too much, eats she not?" So I PREFER "doesn't she", but that's just a personal preference for consistency. (I can think of some examples from very old books, like "You thinketh that he speaks falsely, thinkest thou not?" But I thinkest this usage is mostly obsolete.)

Comment: British English? Group 3 sounds more American to me, and group 1 more British. In American English, we would use "have" for any present perfect participle **except** "got", in which case I believe we prefer group 3 rather than group 1. For example, "You've replied to her email, haven't you?" would be perfectly normal American (and in this case also British) English. In fact, I believe the past participles "got" and "gotten" behave differently in American English in this usage. So it's "you've gotten her email, haven't you," and "you've got her email, don't you."

Comment: "haven't I" is used all the time., "I've made all the efforts I should've made, haven't I?

Comment: @Jay "doesn't she" - "does not she" - sounds pretty unusual and awkward to me!

Comment: @Dan Technically, "Doesn't she?" expands to "Does not she?", which yes, would be awkward. But nevertheless, people say it all the time. I think most would expand it to "Does she not?" Which sounds very formal, but that's why we use the contraction.

Comment: @Jay - hereabouts (UK) 'haven't' is used everywhere; not unusual or awkward.  The issue here is not contractions in themselves.  It is also not about whether 'bad' English "...would be well understood by any English speaker".   The OP is asking for guidance about whether the tag question need 'agree' with the auxiliary associated with the statement ("*...the **right** question tag (in British English)*"

Answer (score 1):

To me the rule is that the verb in the tag question should be the same as the auxiliary verb in the first part of the sentence (affirmative or negative). This may also apply to auxiliary verbs that would be used in the emphatic form of the first part of the sentence, which may or may not appear in such part, and to verbs which can act as both substantive and auxiliary. I would say group 1, 2 and 4 are correct, group 3 is not. I understand language is in a constant process of change (see Noam Chomsky's article 'Transformational Grammar') and what really matters is to make ourselves be understood by others when we use a language. The examples to illustrate my idea of the rule are as follows: 
I've got a good voice, haven't I? (Have - auxiliary)
I (do) have a good voice, don't I? (Do - hidden auxiliary)
I have a good voice, haven't I? (Have - substantive)

In Group 3 'I've got a good voice, don't I?' it is not possible to have 'do' as an hidden auxiliary as this form is already emphasized by 'got'. 'I do have got..' would be wrong. Thus, the tag question 'don't I?' is inconsistent with the verb 'have' in the first part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Groups 1,2 and 4 are fine.  Group 3 is the problem.

In the first example sentence of Group 3 - *I've got a good voice, don't I?* the tag question is using a different auxiliary (do) to the statement that precedes it (have).

Starting "*I've got...*" the tag question is "*...haven't I*?".

Starting with "*I have...*" the tag question can be ***either*** "*... haven't I?*" ***or*** "*... don't I*". UK English tends to use the former and US English the latter, I think.

Answer (score -2):

Group 1&2 are correct.  Because in first group have is a helping verb and sentence is in present perfect tense.... in second group have is a verb and sentence is in simple present tense.... so 1&2 are right

Answer (score -3):

None are correct, take out the apostrophes and then ask do they make sense? don’t you should be do you not and haven't you should be have you not. Not do not you and have not you as they are being used in the former.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This must be a joke because it just is not serious.