# Using can and can't

Tags: question-tags

> She can barely cook a decent meal, ***_*___** she?

I think the answer is *can’t*. Please advise: what is the rule here?

Therefore, if the question is asked:

> She can’t swim, ***_*___** she?

In this case, I think the answer will be *can*.

What do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question tags — "did you" vs. "didn't you"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64646/question-tags-did-you-vs-didnt-you) and also see [“Haven't you?” or “don't you?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46785)

Answer (score 1):

1. > She can barely cook a decent meal, *can* she?

   The emphasis is on *barely*.
2. > She can’t swim, *can* she?

   The emphasis is on *swim*.