# "Hadn't I" vs. "Didn't I"

Tags: grammar

Which one of the sentences is the correct, and why?

> I had breakfast yesterday, **hadn't** I?
>
> I had breakfast yesterday, **didn't** I?

Comment: Proofreading is off topic here. Please see the help section.

Comment: This is basically an exact duplicate of ["Haven't you?" or "don't you?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46785/havent-you-or-dont-you)

Answer (score 4):

I choose option "b" since "had" in this case is a main verb, not an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Right. This _have_ is a part of an idiom _have `Meal`_, meaning 'eat `Meal`', which is a metaphoric extension of 'possess' _have_; only auxiliary _have_ participates in Subject-Auxiliary Inversion.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, good question!

What you're doing is using "tag questions" which are just questions that get stuck onto the end of declarative sentences (like "I had breakfast" or "I like tigers" or "I make tacos on Thursdays") to turn them into...questions!

So here's the thing, questions in English *only* start with auxiliary verbs or questions words. Observe:

Have I eaten?
*Ate I?

Am I running?
*Running am I?

Do I like camels?
*Like I camels?

The same rule applies to tag questions! So even though "have" *can* be an auxiliary verb, it's not one in "I had breakfast." It's the main verb so it *can't* be.

The amazing thing is, you can still form a tag question, or a regular question ("did I eat breakfast?") with the verb "do" which literally means nothing but [tense]! Perfect examples, awesome question.