# "Have you?" vs "do you?" in awkward sentence

Tags: word-choice, auxiliary-verbs, question-tags

This question arises from a debate between friends about what is "technically" more correct in this sentence:

> "You don't happen to have read <book name>, do you?"

Should the question be "do you" as in

> "You **don't** happen..., **do you**?"

or "**have you**" as in "have you read"?

(I understand that there are better ways to write this sentence.)

Comment: Native speakers would probably not use this construction.

Comment: Agree with @GArthurBrown.  You haven’t read <book name> by any chance, have you?

Comment: @Jim Or alternatively: You didn't read *book name* by any chance, did you?

Comment: @GArthurBrown - Yes. Although using “have” focuses the question on the whether that person’s state vector included having read the book or not (it changes who they are in some small way) while “did” focuses on the act of reading.  Have you read “Have you read Homer” vs “Did you read the book that was assigned last week”

Comment: @Jim True, though they are functionally interchangeable when phrased as "Have you read Homer" and "Did you ever read Homer?"

Comment: @GArthurBrown - UK English would only use the perfect tense verb in this case, not the preterite - "Have you (ever) read XX?"

Comment: You don't happen to like westerns, do you? [OK]. To have read is past tense., ERGO, you can't use the present simple tense. Did you happen to read that book? [OK] Do you happen to have read that book, do you?= [buzzer]

Comment: Rys, I worked hard on your behalf. And there is no response from you.

Comment: @Dan [It appears the "did" construction has become less common in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+you+ever+read&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3).

Comment: @GArthurBrown - the only time I would say it is when the whole event is firmly in the past ("Did you ever go to Disneyland when you were in America last year")

Comment: @Dan Have you ever read this book? You have read this book, haven't you? And: You read this book, didn't you? It seems no one here is familiar with tenses. I doubt very highly whether "Did you read this book?" is "less common" in BrE.

Comment: @Lambie - nice try.  Even if someone asked me aggressive/assertively "You read this book, didn't you?" I'm pretty confident I'd pause and say "yes, I have" (or, "No, I haven't").  Americanisms are often very seductive.  I likely use them more than I realise.  But in this case it just sounds wrong.

Comment: Returning to the OP... the only difference, for me, between "Have you read..." and "You don't happen to have read..., do you" is the degree of directness.  Using 'to happen to' makes the interrogation more casual/much less direct.

Comment: @Dan It is not an Americanism to ask a question in the simple past: You ate that scone that was on the tray, didn't you? To say that is simply  frankly. The two verb tenses do not function the same way but in any case, "Do you happen to have read" cannot take the "do you" tag, if you are interested in U speech.

Comment: @Dan "Did you read the book?" is not an Americanism, and, as the Ngram suggests, was more common in older British writings. To suggest that because America has preserved older English forms more in this case than UK speakers that it becomes an Americanism is absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind: The issue here is about the one-off feature of "read that book" and the present simple in English.

I **happen** to like chocolate, **don't** I? I **don't happen** to like pastry, **do I**?. ***General statements about a thing or situation are in the present simple***.

**happen to** does not work well with "a single occurrence of a situation" such as: You don't happen to have read that book. For the present simple to work, you need a general statement: **You don't happen to read mystery stories very often, do you?**

You don't happen to ride your bike there every day, do you? **You didn't happen to read that book, did you**?

Your sentence is not grammatical in English for the present simple, it is not a general statement. **You don't happen to like mystery stories, do you?** [general statement]

So, the issue is not the tag. The issue is the predicate: read that book. single occurrence. Typically in English we say:

- You **didn't happen** to read that book, **did**  you?
- You haven't read that book, have you?
- You've read that book haven't you?
- You read that book, didn't you?

I don't happen to like answering grammar questions much, do I? [general question re grammar questions.]

- I don't happen to have answered this question, do I? [BUZZER]
- I don't happen to listen carefully to others, do ? [OK, general statement]

[**BBC English_ Present Simple**](https://www.bbc.com/learningenglish/spanish/course/intermediate/unit-1/tab/grammar)

> **Present simple We use the present simple tense for things that we do
> regularly and for facts, habits, truths and permanent situations.** We
> often use time expressions like every day, once a week, on Fridays.
>
> I check my email every day. (regular activity) Yuki works at the bank.
> (permanent situation)

For a single occurrence like here (read that book), you can use just about any tense other than the present simple.

[Personal note: Had I not taught English for many years and subsequently become a translator, I never would have been able to figure this out. :)]

PS: In utterances such as: I happen to like a short walk before breakfast. That is OK, as it is a general statement.

Comment: I disagree. The OP's sentence has "to have read" -- perfect infinitive, not present. The only present is in the outer clause. A person's having read some book *B* is a present situation resulting from past action. "Happen" works well  with that. The speaker asks about this present situation, and thus uses "happen" in the present. "Do you happen to have read *B*?" is similar to "Have you, by any chance, read *B*?". This Question seems to have raised some complex linguistic issues, doesn't it.

Comment: Tags comes from a main verb, not a perfect infinitive. **There is zero tag with: Do you happen to have read x?**. No tag at all is possible there. Therefore, you are mistaken.

Comment: you said that the problem was not with the tag, but with the use of the present tense. That's why I used tagless statements for examples.  It is still not clear to me exactly what combo of things you think is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Rosie Sorry, can't do more. The present simple is for general statements. Not one-off statements. **I happen to like chocolates, don't I**? [general] but not: I happen to have eaten that chocolate, don't I?

Comment: Thanks for this amazing response @Lambie!

Comment: @RhysvanderWaerden You are very welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

That is technically correct, because the person **does** or **does not** happen to have read that book, but

"You wouldn't happen to have read [book name], would you?"

works a bit better.

Changing the structure a bit,

"You haven't read [book name], have you?"

works, but it does change the tone a bit in certain contexts from asking if they have read it to assuming or hoping they haven't ("Awww... you didn't eat my pie, did you?").

Comment: Your second version - "You haven't read [book name], have you?" - could also sound patronising/condescending!

Comment: In fact it's the sort of phrase whose meaning can vary enormously depending on emphasis and prosody.

Comment: Yes; it could be spoken to mean the same as OP's sentence with the correct emphasis, but in writing it would be confusing.

Comment: It is technically wrong. in fact.

Comment: @Lambie How is it incorrect?

Comment: Read my answer and you will find out. :) See how you instinctively went to another tense? :) The conditional? That works, the present simple does not.

Comment: Is it not that they, in the present tense, have the attribute of having read the book? They read the book in the past, but they currently have read the book.

Comment: **The present simple is used for generalities**. This is not one. It is specific. Ergo, you can't use the present simple here.

Comment: What would be the correct present tense in that case?

Happy New Year!

Comment: You have read this book, haven't  you? :)

Answer (score -1):

The tag is based on how the main clause is phrased, not on what it means. It is possible that two main clauses with very similar meanings need different tags. So, as you correctly say, it's

"You **don't** happen to have read [book name], **do** you?"

even though it would be

"You **have** read [book name], **haven't** you?"

Comment: Not the whole story. ['Haven't you?' or 'Don't you?'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46785/havent-you-or-dont-you)

Comment: The issue here is not the tag. It is misuse of the present simple. You don't happen to read any  good books, do you?

Comment: @Lambie Why is the issue not the use of the tag? The OP asks about which tag to use. And where is there any misuse of the present simple?

Comment: Because the OP does not realize that the mistake is not the tag. It's the use of the present simple here. Please read my answser.

Comment: You don't happen to have read x, do you? Is not grammatical in English. Surely, you can feel that?

Comment: Alice loves novels, & is starting a literature course. She was reading a piece of paper. When she'd finished, Bob took a look. It was her course's reading list. "You happen to have read some of these, don't you?" // Now "You've read some of these, haven't you?" is OK, but "happen" helps say that of all the books by all the authors in all the world, by lucky chance, some on the list are among those Alice has read. If my example is pragmatically implausible, maybe one with a verb other than "read" would be more plausible, but we're using it because the OP used it, aren't we. @Lambie

Comment: "You happen to have read some of these, don't you?"[Buzzer]

Comment: "You don't happen to have read [book name], do you?" You cannot find any such similar usage in the English canon.

Comment: @GArthurBrown - I happen to have found evidence in favour of the orthodoxy you and Lambie are promoting ... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+you+happen+to+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20you%20happen%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0